# using map fragment on Quickblox

Tags: android-mapview, quickblox, mapfragment

I'm creating an Android Mobile app that contains a map, Quickblox does exactly what I want. The problem is that it uses Map View, which is deprecated. Can someone please show me how to uses Map Fragment or Support Map fragment on quick blox.